# Jack compiler and JaCoCo code coverage

Tags: android, jacoco, android-jack-and-jill

I am using jack compiler in my Android app. [Here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/sdk/+/master/tools/README-jack-code-coverage.md) is a description of how to use JaCoCo with Jack compiler. But I don't understand it. There are talking about changing something in my make command. But I use gradle. Or do I have to build my own Android SDK to get JaCoCo support with jack?